# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio username and password

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Error thrown:

[image]

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: use localhost or a dot (.) or 127.0.0.1

Comment: You are providing a Windows user account when you have SQL Authentication selected.

Comment: Is SQL Server running?  Are the credentials you supply correct?

Comment: i also use localhost but same error is occour every tyme what should i type in password ?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner what should i can write for sqlserver authentication any default username and password is there? or when i am selected window authentication its not asking for username and password

Comment: @Dhru'soni - This is one problem you are having. See Matt's answer below with regards to how to check the service status.

Comment: @Dhru'soni did my answer fix your problems, is there anything else?

Comment: @Matt yes it will work :) thank you so much Matt. Matt did you know how to open Microsoft Excel in side WPF Application With i can perfom all excel operation inside WPF Application

Comment: @Dhru'soni if you ask that as another question I will have a go at answering it for you, would you mind marking the my response below as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is installed locally and is a SQL Server Express instance your server name is likely `(local)\sqlexpress` - try this name.

If this doesn't work then get up the service manager (start > run > services.msc) find the SQL Server service running in the background and the service name should also tell you the instance name (eg. `SQLSERVER(myname)`). In that case then the server name will be `(local)\myname`.

Also are you sure your using SQL Server authentication - this requires you to set up accounts manually. Try changing to Windows authentication and it should log you in using the credentials you logged into windows with.